# Getting method parameter types using scala 2.10 reflection API

Tags: scala, reflection

Using the Java reflection API, to get the list of parameter types for a method we can simply use `getParameterTypes`.

Here's an example:

```
scala> classOf[String].getMethods.head.getParameterTypes

res8: Array[Class[_]] = Array(class java.lang.Object)
```

What's the best practice to get the same result using the the new Scala 2.10 Reflection API?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's more difficult, because Scala reflection does more and need more. For example:

- The types are not erased. The classes are erased, but not the types.
- Scala supports named parameters, so you need the name of the parameters.
- Scala has methods without parameter lists.

So, given all that, here's how you do it. First, get the methods:

```
val stringMethods: Iterable[MethodSymbol] = typeOf[String].members.collect { 
  case m if m.isMethod => m.asMethod 
}
```

Scala reflection doesn't (yet) provide methods to list specific kinds of members (methods, fields, inner classes, etc), so you need to use the general `members` method.

Working for all kinds of members, the `members` method returns an iterable of `Symbol`, the greatest common denominator of all symbols, so you'll need to cast to `MethodSymbol` to treat the resulting symbols as methods.

Now, let's say we have a `MethodSymbol`, and we want the types of arguments. We can do this:

```
method.paramLists
```

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for your answer. it worked well, but I am surprised that scala reflection API doesn't encapsulate this functionality, which seems to be basic.